# Triangle at bottom on hover with border

Tags: html, css, navigation

Basically I have this layout and I'm trying to make the triangle with border appear on hover.

[image]

```css
ul {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul a {
text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover a {
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">shop</a></li>
<li><a href="">contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css pseudo` element to achieve this.
check snippet.

```css
ul {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

ul li:hover a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 5px #fff;
  border-left: solid 5px transparent;
  border-right: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">shop</a></li>
  <li><a href="">contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: can this be done without setting 'position: relative' of li? I've many nested ULs within parent UL and it's messing up those nested ul.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:hover a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover a::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid white;
  left: 39%;
  top: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li><a href="">shop</a></li>
<li><a href="">contact</a></li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```